# Syntax Error Using CASE Expression - Can't Figure Out

Tags: sql-server

Studying SQL and I'm trying out CASE expressions for the first time and I can't figure out where my syntax errors are?

[image]

Comment: Remove the `InvoiceTotal` that's between `CASE` and `WHEN`. Syntax is *either* `CASE x WHEN y THEN z ... END` *or* `CASE WHEN expr THEN z ... END` --- See [syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#syntax) in SQL Server manual.

Comment: And use proper quotes: `'`

Comment: Use proper quotes:

Comment: Please add text in place of image, it gets easy for anybody to cross check.

Comment: Oddly enough, you can't just drop text formatted from your homework into SSMS and add `SELECT ` in front of it to write working tsql. Learn the language, attend class, ask your teacher / assistants for help, make a real effort.

Answer (score 1):

The CASE construction has two possible syntax :

Either **Simple CASE Expression** :

A) `CASE VARIABLE WHEN VALUE1 THEN RESULT1 WHEN VALUE2 THEN RESULT2 ELSE RESULT3 END`

or **Searched CASE Expression** :

B) `CASE WHEN CONDITION1 THEN RESULT1 WHEN CONDITION2 THEN RESULT2 ELSE RESULT3 END`

You have to chose one or the other, but your code is trying to mix both.

To solve your query you just have to remove the first `InvoiceTotal` and use the second syntax.

```
CASE WHEN InvoiceTotal < 100 THEN 'no discount consideration'
     WHEN InvoiceTotal > 101 AND InvoiceTotal < 500 THEN 'Discount potential 3'
...
...
END AS PotentialDiscount
```

PS: your quotes were also wrong, they have to be 'xxx', not ´xxx`

Comment: In SQL Server parlance, the two forms are referred to as ["Simple CASE expression" and "Searched CASE expression"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Good point, thanks. I have updated the answer.